# Recursive function to build an array

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

```
private static function traverseTree($tree,$node)
{
    $nodes = array();
    $results = array();

    $children = $tree->where('parent_id',$node->id)->where('type',UserGroup::DEPARTMENT_TYPE);

    foreach($children as $child){

        $nodes[] = $child->id;
        $children = self::traverseTree($tree,$child);
        $results = array_merge ($nodes,$children);

    }

    return $results;
}
```

I am stepping through it and I can see that the children are getting found but they are not included in the final results.

The final results just contain the top level.

**Detail added:**
$tree is a Laravel Collection, if I pipe this to an array I get:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 21,
    'name' => 'Top',
    'type' => 1,
    'parent_id' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 33,
    'name' => 'UKDept',
    'type' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 21,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 36,
    'name' => 'UKSubDept',
    'parent_id' => 33,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 37,
    'name' => 'USDept',
    'type' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 21,
  ),
)
```

$node:

```
array (
    'id' => 21,
    'name' => 'Top',
    'type' => 1,
    'parent_id' => 0,
),
```

The first call to populate $children gives:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 33,
    'name' => 'UKDept',
    'type' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 21,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 37,
    'name' => 'USDept',
    'type' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 21,
  ),
)
```

Comment: need a lot more information.  what is the initial input $tree` and `$node`?  what does `$chilrden` contain on the initial function call?  what kinds of things are returned by `self::traverseTree($tree,$child);` on the initial function call?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the array outside the function.

```
$nodes = array();
$results = array();

    private static function traverseTree($tree,$node)
    {

        $children = $tree->where('parent_id',$node->id)->where('type',UserGroup::DEPARTMENT_TYPE);

        foreach($children as $child){

            $nodes[] = $child->id;
            $children = self::traverseTree($tree,$child);
            $results = array_merge ($nodes,$children);

        }

        return $results;
    }
```

It will not reinitialize them each time you call the function.Check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$child` is an array but you are treating it like an object.  Try changing:

```
$nodes[] = $child->id;
```

to

```
$nodes[] = $child['id'];
```

Comment: No, its and object. Children is a Laravel collection. It returns some node, just not all.

Comment: ok well i'm just going on the the code you posted which is an array.  if that's not correct then please provide a proper example otherwise it's impossible to answer

Comment: In the original post, I stated: "$tree is a Laravel Collection, if I pipe this to an array I get:"

Answer (score 0):

I have this working now, one stupid mistake I made was:

```
foreach($children as $child){

        $nodes[] = $child->id;
        $children = self::traverseTree($tree,$child);
        $results = array_merge ($nodes,$children);
```

Using $children as a variable name twice!

This is the complete function:

```
private static function traverseTree($tree,$node)
{
    $initialId = array();
    $results = array();

    $results[] = $node->id;

    $children = $tree->where('parent_id',$node->id);


    foreach($children as $node){

        //if this is a department, then we need to go deeper
        if($node->type == DEPARTMENT) {
            $nodesChildren = self::traverseTree($tree, $node);
            $results = array_merge ($results,$nodesChildren);
        }else{
            //just add this node to the results array
            $results[] = $node->id;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```